# How to find the cause code of exception in a sub-threads? (iOS)

Tags: ios, multithreading, exception

I'm a webapp developer but not an iOS developer. Recently I got an iOS project from party A that needs to insert my page into. When they run my page on their app, their app crashed. Here's the exception they sended me.
[image]

The exception is an NSInternalInconsistencyException, and it's reason is 'Call must be made on main thread'.
We have tested several times. Here's the result:

**1. My web app works well in an empty iOS app.**

**2. My web app works well in their app in Android version.**

**3. My web app works well in Safari and other browsers.**

**4. I try to make a dead loop in my page and run in their app. But it only makes the page reload. The crash in page cannot make their app crash.**

I also asked my iOS developer friends. They said the cause of this exception is definitely in their app.
Sadly the developers from party A cannot find the cause and their project cannot shared with me. **I don't know why they can't find the cause, but I do want to help them to fix this bug. I've spend too much time on this project... :<**

Please tell me "how to find the cause code of an exception that occured in a sub-thread in iOS development?". I'll share the answer to developers from party A.

Comment: Some code has determined that it is not running on the main thread and has caused a fatal error as a result. This can only be solved by finding the code that is calling the code that is causing the exception and dispatching it onto the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 If the app runs several sub-threads, how to know the bug in whitch sub-thread?

Comment: You need a proper symbolicated stack trace and it will show the line of native code that caused the main thread violation

Comment: @Paulw11 Is that means we need to write try-catch block in every code that creates a sub-thread? Is there a lib that can shows the trace: exception -> thread -> code in file?

Comment: No. You can't catch this sort of exception. If you get a proper crash dump and get the iOS developers to symbolicate it, it should tell them where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems add try-catch block is the only way to find the cause. The question will be closed.